# TypeError: $(...).modal is not a function within my script

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm getting this issue when I click on "Assign shipping" for multiple items, the code referred by the console is

```
$(document).ready(function() {
//display mp shipping list in popup
    $(document).on('click', '.assign_shipping', function(e) {e.preventDefault();
$('#assign_shipping_form').modal('show');
    });
```

The issue is within line 4, the funny thing is, if I change jquery version to 3. it would allow me to click it but other errors appear related to the app. I'm not sure how to resolve it.

Comment: What are the other errors in the app when you change to version 3?

Comment: Jquery does not IIRC come with a modal out of the box. Do you have something like bootstrap as well?

Answer (score 1):

```
$( ".selector" ).dialog({
    modal: true
});
```

reference to the jquery ui documentation: http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/#option-modal

you seem to be referring to a bootstrap method as per: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/modal/#via-javascript

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are using Bootstrap modal, then either the `#assign_shipping_form` element is not a modal or the script reference is not set before the method is called. Double check and ensure that the bootstrap JS file is referenced.

The same applies if using other vendor.

Comment: Ok but how can you explain this, when I use jquery-3.3.1.min.js it works fine, but when I revert back tojquery-1.11.0.min.js it throws that error, so you could say, then why don't stick with the 3.3.1.min.js version, The thing is that when it makes the button work other functionalities break down, I'm using prestashop and they are using the jquery-1.11.0.min.js version